# Pandas dataframe not acting as expected once deployed to heroku (Django project)

Tags: python, django, pandas, heroku

I have created a program which does data entry and returns a pandas table (the info is saved in a list, called JOB_INFO, at the top of the views.py file - I will attach this below) with some results which can be downloaded. I also have the table rendering on the html page that has the data entry form - the table renders below the form and updates(appends) with each user input(form submit). This is works perfectly in development on my local machine, but when it's been successfully deployed to heroku, it starts acting up and not behaving as expected.

Examples include:
Not updating the table - the form seems to submit but the table doesn't update. If I keep trying, it suddenly works. But then I'll try another and the previous one disappears and only the latest one will show in the table. It just seems so random.
Not emptying the list - I have a button to clear the table but that doesn't work either. If I click the button a bunch of time it might work suddenly. But then randomly some information will show up in the table again that I thought was cleared!
Info in downloaded file when I thought I cleared it - this one is kind of self-explanatory.

In a nutshell, calling it random is probably the best way to describe it. It's just not doing what I want it to do and what is expected of it.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404, reverse, HttpResponse
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist, MultipleObjectsReturned
from .models import Data
from .forms import DataForm, SearchAndUpdateForm
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter


JOB_INFO = {
    "Plentific Job Number": [],
    "WorkOrder Number": [],
    "Invoice Number Found": [],
    "Payments": [],
    "Job Number Exists": [],
} 


def data_entry(request):
    """
    Creates new instance of data entry form and renders it on html page
    along with a report table, which updates with each data entry input
    """

    form = SearchAndUpdateForm()

    df = pd.DataFrame(JOB_INFO,
        columns=[
            "Plentific Job Number",
            "WorkOrder Number",
            "Invoice Number Found",
            "Payments",
            "Job Number Exists",
        ])

    if not df.empty:
        df_html = df.to_html(classes="table table-striped table-hover")
        return render(request, "data_entry.html", {
            "form": form, "df_html": df_html})
    else:
        return render(request, "data_entry.html", {
                "form": form})


def export_job_info_report(request):
    """
    Exports the job_info list as an Excel spreadsheet
    and saves it to user's local directory
    """

    df = pd.DataFrame(JOB_INFO)

    output = BytesIO()
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='report', index=False)
    writer.save()
    output.seek(0)
    response = HttpResponse(output,
        content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s.xlsx' % 'Download'

    return response


def clear_report_info(request):
    """Empties the job_info dictionary"""

    JOB_INFO["Plentific Job Number"].clear()
    JOB_INFO["WorkOrder Number"].clear()
    JOB_INFO["Invoice Number Found"].clear()
    JOB_INFO["Payments"].clear()
    JOB_INFO["Job Number Exists"].clear()

    return redirect(reverse(data_entry))
```

html page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<div class="jumbotron">

    <h1>Data Entry Tool:</h1>

    <form action="{% url 'search_update_feedback' %}" method="GET">
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Updates the database with the info provided above">
            Update and Fetch Info
        </button>
    </form>

    <br>

    <form action="{% url 'export_job_info_report' %}" method="GET">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Downloads the report below in .xlsx format">
            Download Report
        </button>
    </form>

    <br>

    <form action="{% url 'clear_report_info' %}" method="GET">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Warning! You will lose all of the data below (does not affect database data)">
            Clear Report - hover over me!
        </button>
    </form>

</div>

<hr>

{{ df_html | safe }}

{% endblock %}
```

urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", data_entry, name="data_entry"),
    path("export_job_info_report/", export_job_info_report, name="export_job_info_report"),
    path("clear_report_info/", clear_report_info, name="clear_report_info"),
]
```

Of course I have left out a whole lot of functionality to save reading time but please let me know if anything else can/should be added to help understand the issue.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by replacing the JOB_INFO list with a new Django Model with the same field names, like this:

```
from django.db import models

class JobInfoReport(models.Model):
"""The following are prefixed with 'r' to represent report"""

r_plentific_job_number = models.CharField(max_length=7)
r_wo_number = models.CharField(max_length=6)
r_invoice_number_found = models.CharField(max_length=5)
r_payments = models.CharField(max_length=100)
r_job_number_exists = models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.r_plentific_job_number
```